# Смена css темы на сайте

Tags: javascript, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Подскажите способы, как можно реализовать смену темы на сайте. Например есть светлая и темная тема. Каким образом ее менять?

Я пока вижу только один вариант это делать два css файла, соответственно и переключать их в зависимости от выбора пользователя. Их выбор хранить в куках или бд и тд.. Вообщем наверно это плохой вариант.

Comment: это самый обычный вариант, не парьтесь

Comment: Вы верно всё написали. Создаём куку theme = theme_name и при загрузке проверяем имя темы, и в зависимости от него - грузим нужные стили

Comment: А это разве не делается добавлением и удалением классов? Зачем такие неоптимальные методы?